# Onstop() not working

Tags: java, android, service

I'm try to use the `onStop()` method, but the code is not executed when it's called.
I'm using a TabHost to move from an activity to another.

This code should work when I move to another tab.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(BatteryActivity.this);
    prefs.edit().putInt("BatteryActivity", Answer).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt("Battery", 10).apply();


}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "600", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ((MyApplication) BatteryActivity.this.getApplication()).setAnswerList(200);
    int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
    int idx = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton); // ID of selected radiobutton

    switch(idx){
         case R.id.RadioButton11:

               BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 23 ;

               break;

         case R.id.RadioButton08:
               BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 24 ;

               break;

         }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `onStop()` explicitely?

Comment: not guaranty to call `onStop` method , use `onPause` instead of that

Comment: you should use onResume() and onPause(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Unable to pause activity

Comment: Unable to pause activity???? why ?

Comment: when using if statement inside OnPuse() it's not execute the if statement and jump that , why ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this problem on many forms.
It seems you want to do some work whenever a tab selection is changed. Prefer way to use OnTabChangeListener. Here is a simple example.

```
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (currentActivity instanceof XYZActivity) {
           int ans =  ((XYZActivity) currentActivity).getAnswer();// this method is written in XYZActivity
        }      
    }
});
```

This is just to give you an idea. Actual solution can be provided if you elaborate actual scenario.